# Take screenshot in QThread loop causes app to quit

Tags: python, pyqt

With the following code I'm able to create a splash screen with PyQt and then spawn a thread which emits a signal to update a QLabel. The QThread has a timer-delayed loop which emits a QString-containing signal, and, when the main app receives it, the QLabel on the splash screen is dynamically updated: so I've verified that this general approach works.

The problem is when I try to take a screenshot on every iteration of the loop. What I'm seeing is that the app simply quits without any error messages or warnings. `print` statements indicate that it is the screenshot step which is somehow causing the app to quit, i.e., removing this one line makes the app function properly.

Is there a way to fix this, or at the very least find out what may be causing this problem?

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import (Qt, SIGNAL, pyqtSignal, QObject)
from PyQt4.QtGui import (QApplication, QDialog, QLineEdit, QTextBrowser,
        QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QSplashScreen, QLabel)
import random
import time
import sys
import pyscreenshot
class Worker(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        print("hello world")


    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()
        print 'del'
    def run(self):

        print 'in'
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            a = range(0, 500)

            pyscreenshot.grab_to_file('/home/rm/f.png') #this is the problem
            self.emit( QtCore.SIGNAL('update(QString)'), "<font color=red size=72><b>{0}</b></font>".format(str(random.choice(a))) )   


class Form(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None): 
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        message = 'hello'

        self.label = QLabel("<font color=red size=72><b>{0}</b></font>".format(message))
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.SplashScreen)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        self.label.show()  
        self.resize(1250, 50)

        okButton = QPushButton("&OK")
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(okButton)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.connect(okButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.run)

    def changelab(self, msg):
        print '************************', msg
        self.label.setText(msg)


    def run(self):

        self.workThread = Worker()
        self.connect( self.workThread, QtCore.SIGNAL("update(QString)"), self.changelab )
        self.workThread.start()      



app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Form()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: can you move calling `grab_to_file` to `Form` slot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the PyQt back end of pyscreenshot is not thread safe. It looks like it uses `QPixmap`s which a quick google indicates shouldn't be used outside of the GUI thread. I'd suggest forcing a different back end (if any are thread safe) or use a `QTimer` to take the screenshots from the main thread.

Comment: The second suggestion, taking the screenshots from the main thread worked, i.e. when the QThread emits a signal connected to a method in the main thread to grab the screenshot it works